# Two divs next to each other, stack with responsive change

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something without changing the HTML by only making changes to the CSS.

At two columns the textarea-div width should be double,
At one column the textarea-div width should not be changed,

https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/c314f9-1567495199.png
Sorrym I cannot post an image as I have no reputation

```
<style>
.paragraph {line-height: 20px;display: inline-block;padding: 4px;}
.text,.textarea{display: block;width: 200px;}
</style>

<div class="form form_shortcode">
 <form target="_self" method="post">
  <p class="paragraph"><input type="text" class="text"></p>
  <p class="paragraph"><input type="email" class="text"></p>
  <p class="paragraph"><input type="text" class="text"></p>
  <p class="paragraph"><input type="text" class="text"></p>
  <p class="paragraph"><textarea class="textarea" rows="3"></textarea></p>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: important note: "without changing the HTML by only making changes to the CSS.". Thus, unfortunately I cannot change the HTML. I can only do CSS adjustments

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following css to achieve this. I added comments for explanation, but feel free to ask if something's unclear.

```
.form_shortcode > form {
  font-size: 0; /* needed to remove space between inline-blocks */
}
.paragraph {
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%; /* set to half of parent's width */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* don't add padding to total width */
  font-size: initial; /* reset font-size 0 */
}
.paragraph:last-child {
  width: 100%; /* make last one span the full width */
}
.text,
.textarea{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .paragraph {
    width: 100%; /* set all to full width */
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw3ybteq/

Comment: Sorry to disturb: "textarea" is not the last child. There are several paragraph-divs underneath. How do I adjust the CSS if I have several paragraph-divs underneath textarea-div. So only textarea div is width 200%

Comment: @ict do they all only have the class `.paragraph`? Or is there a way to differentiate the text-paragraphs from the input-paragraphs? Or can you say for sure that e.g. the first 5 paragraphs will have input elements?

Comment: all following also have the .paragraph, but with an exception. the following .paragraph underneath the textarea do not have "input type". I fear that I cannot define a particular paragraph parent to have width 200% if its child is a textarea :(. Hopefully there is another solution. Only the first 4 paragraph have input elements, then textarea (with width 200%), followed by 2 checkboxes (which are not shown in picture, nor in my html above

Comment: [Try this, if the following paragraphs should also be 50% width](https://jsfiddle.net/s4czkeqd/), or [use this, if the following paragraphs should behave normally](https://jsfiddle.net/s4czkeqd/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much! :nth-child(5n) is the solution!

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe you will want to use `nth-child(5)` which selects only the fifth element, while `(5n)` selects every fifth element (so elements 5, 10, 15, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this can be done changing only the css.

You can always use containers with `display: block`

```
<style>
.paragraph {line-height: 20px;display: inline-block;padding: 4px;}
.text,.textarea{display: block;width: 200px;}
.container {display: block}
</style>

<div class="form form_shortcode">
 <form target="_self" method="post">
  <div class="container">
      <p class="paragraph"><input type="text" class="text"></p>
      <p class="paragraph"><input type="email" class="text"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <p class="paragraph"><input type="text" class="text"></p>
      <p class="paragraph"><input type="text" class="text"></p>
  </div>
  <p class="paragraph"><textarea class="textarea" rows="3"></textarea></p>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That is the challange, as I wrote before: "without changing the HTML by only making changes to the CSS.". Thus, unfortunately I cannot change the HTML. I can only do CSS adjustments

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, you are right, I had not read the question properly